# Works in Eclipse, not in JAR file - Class.forName() seemingly not throwing Exception, but code immediately transfers to finally block

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

First, this works in Eclipse but not when running the generated JAR file.  It doesn't seem to generate any exception when the JAR is run, but rather, the code execution stops at the Class.forName() call and immediately transfers to the finally block.  You can see this in the System.out.println() calls (or lack thereof).

Output in Eclipse:

*Finding class...
Getting connection for log population...
Got connection for log population...
In finally block...
Finished.*

Output when JAR file is run:

```
C:\me\myProgram>java -cp MyJar.jar;mssql-jdbc-12.4.0.jre11.jar com.me.myProgram.Main
Finding class...
In finally block...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.me.myProgram.logResults(Comparison.java:449)
        at com.me.myProgram.run(Comparison.java:547)
        at com.me.myProgram.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

I know it's not an issue with the class not being found (or at least really doesn't look like it) because if I change to Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.blahblah"); then I get:

```
D:\me\myProgram>java -cp MyJar.jar;mssql-jdbc-12.4.0.jre11.jar com.me.myProgram.Main
Finding class...
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDrive
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDrive
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at com.me.myProgram.Comparison.logResults(Comparison.java:392)
        at com.me.myProgram.Comparison.run(Comparison.java:547)
        at com.me.myProgram.Main.main(Main.java:13)
In finally block...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.me.myProgram.Comparison.logResults(Comparison.java:449)
        at com.me.myProgram.Comparison.run(Comparison.java:547)
        at com.me.myProgram.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

Code  (line 449 is con.close()):

```
public void logResults(){
        Connection con = null;      
        Boolean success = isJobRowCountMatch && isEntryCountMatch && isExtractCountMatch && (isDeltaPresent || isFullPresent);
        String informationalString = getInformationalString(), issueString = getIssueString(), badEntriesString = 
                getBadEntriesString();
        try {           
            System.out.println("Finding class...");
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            System.out.println("Getting connection for log population...");
            fw.write("Getting connection for log population..." + System.lineSeparator());
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
            System.out.println("Got connection for log population...");
            PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(logPreparedStatement);
            java.sql.Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(d);
            st.setTimestamp(1, ts);
            st.setBoolean(2, success);
            st.setNString(3, informationalString);
            st.setNString(4, issueString);
            st.setNString(5, badEntriesString);
            fw.write("Inserting log entry..." + System.lineSeparator());
            if(outputLogFile.createNewFile() || outputLogFile.exists()) {
                fw.write("Job timestamp: " + month + "-" + day + 
                        "-" + year + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                fw.write("Informational entries: " + informationalString + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                fw.write("Issue entries: " + issueString + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                fw.write("Non-matching list entries: " + badEntriesString + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
            else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Can't create log file " + outputLogFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            int resultCount = st.executeUpdate();
            if(resultCount == 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Log entry couldn't be inserted to the database for some reason.");
            }
            fw.write("Log entry inserted." + System.lineSeparator());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException("Problem inserting log entry into database: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            System.out.println("In finally block...");
            try {
                con.close();  //NPE happens here
            }
            catch(java.sql.SQLException sqle) {             
                sqle.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       
    }
    
    private void loadProps() {
        java.util.Properties props = null;
        try{
            File dir = new File(AccuityComparison.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().
                    getPath());
            
            java.io.InputStream stream = new java.io.FileInputStream(
                    dir.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "config.properties");
            props = new java.util.Properties();
            props.load(stream);
            stream.close();
        }
        catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            fnfe.printStackTrace();
            try {
                fw.write(fnfe.getMessage());
                fw.close();
            }
            catch(java.io.IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not find properties file \"config.properties\": " +
                    fnfe.getMessage());
        }
        catch(java.io.IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            try {
                fw.write(ioe.getMessage());
                fw.close();
            }
            catch(java.io.IOException ioe2) {
                ioe2.printStackTrace();
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to read from properties file \"config.properties\": " +
                    ioe.getMessage());
        }
        logPreparedStatement = props.getProperty("logPreparedStatement");
        extractSummaryDir = props.getProperty("extractSummaryDir");
        archiveDir = props.getProperty("archiveDir");
        connectionString = props.getProperty("connectionString");
        jobCountQueryDelta = props.getProperty("jobCountQueryDelta");
        jobCountQueryFull = props.getProperty("jobCountQueryFull");
        dbEntryCountQueryFull = props.getProperty("dbEntryCountQueryFull");
        dbEntryCountQueryDelta = props.getProperty("dbEntryCountQueryDelta");
        dbEntriesQueryFull = props.getProperty("dbEntriesQueryFull");
        dbEntriesQueryDelta = props.getProperty("dbEntriesQueryDelta"); 
        dbConnStringPwd = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(props.getProperty("connectionStringPwd")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        connectionString += dbConnStringPwd;
        System.out.println("Conn string = " + connectionString);
    };
    
    public void run(){
        Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Starting...");
        try{
            fw = new java.io.FileWriter(outputLogFile);         
            fw.write("Thread starting..." + System.lineSeparator());
            loadProps();
            fullFile = new java.io.File(archiveDir + "Full_" + month + "-" + day + "-" + year + ".xml");
            deltaFile = new java.io.File(archiveDir + "Delta_" + month + "-" + day + "-" + year + ".xml");
            if(fullFile.exists()) {
                isFullPresent = true;
                type = "Full";
                populateSetFromListFile();
                runCount();
            }
            else {
                fw.write("Full file: " + fullFile + " not present." + System.lineSeparator());
                informational.add("Full list file not present.");
            }
            listSet.clear();
            if(deltaFile.exists()) {
                isDeltaPresent = true;
                type = "Delta";
                populateSetFromListFile();
                runCount();
            }       
            else {
                fw.write("Delta file: " + deltaFile + " not present." + System.lineSeparator());
                informational.add("Delta list file not present.");
            }                       
            String exceptionText = (!isJobRowCountMatch ? "There is a count mismatch between the list file (" + listSet.size() + ")" + 
                    " and the job row count in WLF_JOBS_log (" + jobRowCount + ").  " : "") + 
                    (!isExtractCountMatch ? " There is a mismatch between the list entries (" + listSet.size() + 
                        ") and the extract summary file count (" + extractCount + ").  ": "") +
                    (!isEntryCountMatch ? " There is a mistmatch between the filtered list entries (" + filteredListCount +  
                    ") and the database entry count in WLF_LATEST_LIST_ENTRIES (" + dbEntryCount + ").  " : "" + 
                    (badEntries.size() > 0 ? "One or more list entries does not seem to be fully intact." : ""));
            if(exceptionText.length() > 0 && (isDeltaPresent || isFullPresent))
                issues.add(exceptionText);
            logResults();                   
            fw.write("Program finished." + System.lineSeparator() + "Program executed in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " milliseconds.");
            fw.close();
            if((isDeltaPresent || isFullPresent) && (!isJobRowCountMatch || !isExtractCountMatch || !isEntryCountMatch || (badEntries.size() > 0)))
                throw new RuntimeException(exceptionText);
        }
        catch(java.io.IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            try {
                fw.write(ioe.getMessage());
                fw.close();
            }
            catch(java.io.IOException ioe2) {
                ioe2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }           
        System.out.println("Finished.");
    }   
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Show us `Comparison`. Especially show us `logResults`. I'm *tempted* to [close as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/2970947).

Comment: The README in https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc mentions a number of dependencies that don't seem to be on your command line. Are you using something like Maven that provides them to Eclipse?

Comment: Line numbers on the code please. How are we supposed to know which lines correspond to the stacktrace?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This is inside of the logResults() function, but I suppose I can include the entire class.  I've been scolded here before for doing that. nitind: what do you mean?  Works fine in Eclipse and is not Mavenized.  aled: you have the System.out.println lines for where the code stops execution, but I suppose I could include them.

Comment: Edited to show all of logResults() and to indicate that 449 is con.close()

Comment: Something is missing in the command line execution that makes it work in Eclipse. Probably some dependency.

Comment: @aled you weren't too far off with thinking about dependencies.  I'll solve this question momentarily and you'll see more detail (JDBC JAR file was incorrect version).

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps someone in the future.  I removed the finally block and then the exception came as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

I forgot that I had downgraded my compiler compliance version in my Eclipse project due to a lower version of Java on our production box.  Strange behavior of the driver and certainly left me scratching my head, and it wasn't apparent until removing that finally block.  Going to use the JRE8 version of the MSSQL JDBC driver now.